# $f$ continuous a.e. implies $f$ measurable.

Tags: measure-theory

I want prove that if $f:\mathbb {R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous a.e., then $f$ is measurable.

I put $ \mathbb {R}^n=C\cup D$ with $C$ the continuity set of $f$ and $D$ the discontinuity set. I know that $\mu(D)=0$.

Now, the set $\{f<a\}$ can be write as $(\{f<a\}\cap C)\cup (\{f<a\}\cap D)$.

$(\{f<a\}\cap D)$ is measurable because is into $D$, a set with null measure.

Here is my problem: can I say that: $\{f<a\}\cap C=\{f_{\vert C}<a\}$? If I can, this set is measurable because $ f_{\vert C}$ is continuous, and the problem finish.

Any other solution? Thanks!

Comment: Yes Sir! Moved to Answer.

Answer (score 0):

$f|_C$ is continuous, and therefore measurable. $f|_D$ is measurable because ANY subset of $D$ is measurable. Finally, whenever the restrictions of a function to two measurable subsets are measurable, the restriction to the union of the two subsets is also measurable. (Prove this as a separate, easy, but important preliminary observation.) Now you are done.

Comment: If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is prescribed by $x\mapsto1$ if $x\in\mathbb Q$ and $x\mapsto1+x$ otherwise then $C=\{0\}$ but $f|_C=1_{\{0\}}$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: @drhab - Brilliant observation! But please explain how ANY function on $C$, a single-point set, can be discontinuous. Bravo regardless.

Comment: If $f$ is a function that has a singleton as domain then it is automatically a constant function so also a continuous function. So if $f|C$ stands for a function having $C$ as domain then it is continuous. Is that what you meant with $f|C$ in your question? I read it as $f1_C$ having $\mathbb R$ as domain.

Comment: @drhab - I meant EXACTLY what I wrote, not something else. It should have been clear too, when I said "whenever the restriction of a function to TWO measurable SUBSETS..." - that probably also flew over your head.

Comment: I think you are correct in stating that $f|C$ (as a function with $C$ as domain) is continuous, but doesn't that need a proof in this context? See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2536411/75923) for example.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot withdraw my downvote anymore (too late) neither upvote.

Comment: @drhab - don't worry about votes, I don't care about them (it's an idiotic system in my opinion anyway). To your question: A function is always continuous on its continuity set! And a continuous function is measurable. Are you asking if this fact must be proved? In any case - I posted this as a Comment (Hint) to the OP, who asked me to post it as an Answer instead - this is why it is so brief.