# If $ f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous a.e on $\mathbb{R}$, show that $f$ is a Lebesgue measurable function

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure

I intend to solve an exercise below :

**If $ f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous a.e on $\mathbb{R}$, show that $f$ is a Lebesgue measurable function.**

I try to answer :

Let $\mathbb{R}$ be measurable and let $D$ be the set of discontinuous of $f$.

Then $\mu(D)=0$ and all of its subsets are measurable. Let $r \in \mathbb{R}$ and note that $$ \{x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) \gt r \}=\left\{x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus D:f(x) \gt r\} \cup \{x \in D:f(x) \gt r\right\}.$$

We need to show that $$ C = \{x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus D : f(x) \gt r\}$$ is measurable for each $x \in C$, as $f$ is continuous at $x$, we can find that $\delta_x \gt 0$ such that if $y \in V_{\delta_x}(x)$ then $f(y) \gt r$. It is clear that $$ C = (\mathbb{R}\setminus D) \cap \cup_{x \in C} V_{\delta_x}(x)$$

is this true ? Hope anyone can check my answer.Thank you

Comment: Correct or not (see the answer of José), I think it will not be quite helpful to prove that $C$ is Lebesgue measurable. This because $\bigcup_{x\in C}V_{\delta_x}(x)$ is not a countable union.

Answer (score 1):

For every  $y\in\{x\in\mathbb R-D\mid f(x)>r\}$ we can find an open set $U_y$ such that $y\in U_y$ and $z\in U_y\implies f(z)>r$.

If $U$ denotes the union of these sets then $U$ is open and: $$\{x\in\mathbb R-D\mid f(x)>r\}=U\cap(\mathbb R-D)$$

So the set is evidently Lebesgue measurable.

Then $\{x\in\mathbb R\mid f(x)>r\}$ is - as union of two Lebesgue measurable sets - also Lebesgue measurable.

Answer (score 0):

You did not define $V_\delta$. I suppose that $V_\delta=(x-\delta,x+\delta)$.

If we define$$C_r=(\mathbb{R}\setminus D)\cap\{x\in\mathbb{R}\,|\,f(x)>r\},$$then, since\begin{align}C_r&=\bigcup_{x\in C_r}\{x\}\\&\subset(\mathbb{R}\setminus D)\cap\bigcup_{x\in C_r}V_{\delta_x}\\&\subset C_r,\end{align}then, indeed$$C_r=(\mathbb{R}\setminus D)\cap\bigcup_{x\in C_r}V_{\delta_x}.$$